# A program to arrange the array members into ascending order

Tags: c

what is wrong in this code of c language? 
It is supposed to arrange the array members into ascending order.

#### Code

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main()
{
    int a[5];
    int x,temp,i=0,j=0;
    clrscr();

    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)/*To Enter the data into array*/
    {
        printf("Enter the %d number: ",i);
        scanf("%d",a[i]);
    }

    x=a[0];

    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        for(j=i;j<=4;j++)
        {
            if(x <= a[j])
            {
                temp=a[j];
                a[j]=x;
                x=temp;
                printf("%d %d %d\n",temp,a[j],x);

                /*To check the current value of temp, a[j] and x.*/

                getch(); 
            }
        }
    }

    for(i=0;i<=4;i++)
    {
        printf("%d\n",a[i]);
    }
    getch();
}
```

#### Input

1,2,3,4,5 for the respective elements of the array.

#### Result

I am getting output as :

```
64
5091 64 5091
12803 5091 12803
64
64
-29346
5091
-28724
```

What should be the correct code for this logic.

Comment: Start with `scanf("%d",a[i]);` should be `scanf("%d", &a[i]);`.  If your compiler didn't tell you about the mistake, you either need to turn on more warnings or need a better compiler. When you've fixed that, you will likely find that `x=a[0];` is misplaced; I think it should be inside the outer loop (but outside the inner loop), and written `x = a[i];`

Comment: This is called "sorting"; that ought to give you a clue for searching.

Comment: Thank you Jonathan Leffler but i have turbo c++ ide and it didn't showed any type of warning or error. Which ide i should use to avoid sch mistakes.... Thanks for the answer afterall...

Comment: @Arpit , You are using an IDE which is 20+ year old. Things have changed nowadays. If you want to be a good programmer,please upgrade your IDE. You can also just get a decent compiler like GCC and use a text editor to type the code and compile via the command line for simple programs like the one you have.

Comment: Thankx Cool Guy for the suggestion i am going to do that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`scanf("%d",a[i]);` should be `scanf("%d", &a[i]);`

Comment: Thank you very much willys....really a silly mistake but changed the whole scenario of the output.....

Answer (score 0):

In addition to willys change, your logic just compares all element contents with a[0], you need to consider all the elements within an array, hence change you if condition and content as below:

```
if(a[i] >=  a[j])
{
    temp=a[j];
    a[j]=a[i];
    a[i]=temp;
}
```

Comment: thanks almas shaikh i have got what you said....and i will do that....i would have done it but i struck at that silly point of scanf ampersand.but thnax for the suggestion....

Comment: You are welcome Arpit. It happens when you start and as and when you get handson you yourself will be in a position to identify the issues.

Comment: @Arpit , Its called "Accepting" an answer. No . You can't. Just mark the best one. You can give the answerers some credit by upvoting their answers. You'll get that privilege once you attain 15 reputation

Comment: Ok Cool Guy and thankx for the suggestion.....and telling me the exact terminology "Accepting"...